# Azure Media Services Live Events Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I’m running an application in which I have several live events (video broadcasts) every week.

I would like to know how many viewers I have for these events. Is there any way of finding this information in some service that Azure offers in their Media Services product or another cloud product I can combine it with, or do I have to code such analytics myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the number of view of your live steams, then something outlined in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-metrics-diagnostic-logs) should assist you by logging the number of HTTP requests per stream.

If you're looking for a service that will analyze your videos, the Azure Media Services Product Group [announced a preview product over the the summer called Live Video Analytics](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things/introducing-live-video-analytics-from-azure-media-services-now/ba-p/1406917).